# Intuit Payment : How to move from test environment to production environment

Tags: payment-gateway, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, merchant-account

I am using Intuit's Quickbooks Merchant Services. I am done with testing and it works fine so I decided to move the merchant to live.

> - I've created a new application on http://appreg.intuit.com/ ,
> - chose desktop mode
> - and clicked production environment
> - filled up the fields
> - clicked create app

Then App ID and App Login was generated.
I've got my ticket id, and plugged in the values on my site.

I've also change this code:
`$MS->useTestEnvironment(true); // test`  
to `$MS->useTestEnvironment(false); // live`

When I tested it, VISA cards got in and have the status "pending".. When I tried to use AMEX card, the transaction wasn't processed and got the status "Declined". I've tried this several times but it always says 'declined'.

What could be the problem? is there something need to be changed aside from the APP Log in and App Ticket? Do I need to reg an app in hosted (web app) mode?

I hope my question is clear enough for someone to suggest a solution. It would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting back a status of `Pending` or `Declined`, then you moved from testing to production successfully.

> What could be the problem?

You need to contact Intuit and ask them this. This is a problem that's unrelated to programming that only Intuit will be able to answer.

Give them the transaction IDs of the transactions and ask them why it was declined. They may have you contact the bank that issued the credit cards as well.

> is there something need to be changed aside from the APP Log in and App Ticket?

No.

> Do I need to reg an app in hosted (web app) mode?

No.